# Creating an object with several properties through each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

It's been awhile since I worked with objects so I need to refresh my memory. What I need help with is how to create an object in an each loop with several properties. Below is what I've tried so far but that's obviously not correct.

```
var imgs = {},
    i = 0;

$('.img').each(function() {
    i++;

    imgs['img' + i]['src'] = src;  // doesn't work

    // imgs['img' + i] = src; <- works but I want several properties for every image.
});
```

**desired output:**

```
imgs: {
    img1: {
        src: 'http://...',
        otherProp: '...'
    },
    img2: {
        src: 'http://...',
        otherProp: '...'
    },
    and so on...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the simplest solution:

```
var imgs = {};

$('.img').each(function(index) {
    imgs['img' + index] = {
        src: src,
        otherProp: ...
        ...
    };
});
```

Comment: Yep, this was great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new object with  `imgs['img' + i] = {};` and  set the `src` property and it's value to that object.

something like

```
$('.img').each(function() {
    i++;
    imgs['img' + i] = {};  //on each iteration created the new object
    imgs['img' + i]['src'] = src;  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
imgs['img' + i]['src'] = $(this).attr('src');
```